# JAX-RS consuming a custom object list inside a custom object

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, cxf, jax-rs

What is the way to consume a list of custom objects inside another custom object in JAX-RS CXF implementation? As an example my object looks like below

```
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("test")
public Response myMethod(MyCustomObject myCustomObject) {
```

Inside MyCustomObject it has a list of another custom object which reside inside this as an inner class

```
  public class MyCustomObject {

        private List<MyInner> innerObjects;

        public class MyInner {
            private String property;
            ....
        }
        ....
}
```

Request JSON object is passed as the POST body of the request. When I debug this I could get the MyCustomObject passed properly while I am sending the innerObjects list as null. But it seems its not picking this correctly when I have this array based structure there with a custom object. Additionally instead of this custom object array when I have a primitive type or a string based array the service works fine. How to deal with the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because of the inner class.

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289964/jackson-json-type-mapping-inner-class)

Not sure what mapper you use (cxf default is jettison but it is all configurable), but the case is probably similar.

[Great explanation here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html)

> non-static inner classes (including anonymous ones) have set of hidden variables added by compiler, passed via (hidden) constructor. And as a consequence, do not have zero-argument ("default") constructor

Comment: Yes its because of the inner classes. Making it a concrete class fixed it. Thank your for your answer.