# Converting java object with nested classes to Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have been trying to create json from a java object / class that has a nested class.  However only the top level class is output in Json.  I want to return json from a web services application or alternatively covert json to a java object with nested classes

```
public class JsonData {
    static String firstName;
    static String lastName;
    static String streetName;
    static String cityName;
    static String stateName;

    static PersonalInfo personalInfo = new PersonalInfo(); 

 //  typical set and get followed by the nested class
     static class PersonalInfo {
     String height;
     String weight;
     String eyeColor;
     String favoriteColor;
     // getter's and setters for this class
     }
   }

    // in a separate method that handles the web service request set the values... 

   @RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String sendJsonSample() throws JsonGenerationException {
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println("\nReceived Request for json data what happens now ! \n");
    JsonData jsonData = new JsonData();
    jsonData.setCityName("New York");
    jsonData.setFirstName("Fred");
    jsonData.setLastName("Smith");
    jsonData.setStateName("NY");
    jsonData.setStreetName("Broadway");
    JsonData.personalInfo.setEyeColor("Green");
    JsonData.personalInfo.setFavoriteColor("Yellow");
    JsonData.personalInfo.setHeight("SixFeet");
    JsonData.personalInfo.setWeight("180");

      // now convert to json with the following
      try {
        String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonData);
        return json;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }       
      return "ERROR"
     }

    // if I use a browser to my controller http://localhost:8080/json the json returned to my web services call only includes the top or outer level class 
    {
      stateName: "NY",
      firstName: "Fred",
      lastName: "Smith",
      streetName: "Broadway",
      cityName: "New York"
    }

    // I would have expected or I want I should say 
    {
     "state": "NY",
     "firstName": "Fred",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "streetName": "Broadway",
     "cityName": "New York",
     "PersonalInfo": {
       "EyeColor":"Green",
       "FavoriteColor": "Yellow",
       "height":"SixFeet",
       "Weight":"189"
     }
    }
```

Comment: Why are all your fields `static`? Jackson shouldn't be serializing those at all.

Comment: It will if you have instance accessors, though. It's very unclear why you get this behavior without a proper [MCVE]. Please add one now.

Comment: In researching this I have seen suggestions that the inner class be static, is this not the case?  Is this the problem?

Comment: The _nested_ class can be `static`. The field, presumably, shouldn't.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. Get rid of the Spring MVC code, include your getters, etc.

Comment: Wow sorry, I was trying to be "complete" not knowing I was exceeding "minimal"

Answer (score 0):

Jackson serializes objects and instance properties. Your class defines all of its members as _class_members -- i.e., static. That means that no matter how many objects are instantiated from your class, there will be only *one* value for each static property. Every piece of code that sets the value of one of those properties will change it for every other piece of code reading it.

Perhaps you have made your properties static because your PersonalInfo nested class class is static. Remove the static modifier from your PersonalInfo class. Even better, make it a top-level class and remove the static modifier.

An aside: Because your code will be used in a web application, your class will be instantiated by many threads. Using non-final static members in data classes such as this is ***very, very hazardous***. All of your clients will be sharing the same data.

Comment: The class being nested and `static` is not an issue. Making it non-static will complicate and potentially break things further as Jackson won't necessarily have an enclosing instance to instantiate it with.

Comment: This is simply a sample app to get this to work the hazards are understood. I'm still not understanding why the output json is not as I would expect.  Thanks

Comment: Not serializing static members would have been a design decision by the Jackson developers. I have to ask why would you ever want the properties such as these to be static?

Comment: The properties are definitely at the heart of the issue. The class declaration is not.

Comment: You're right Sotirios -- I was thinking of the inner class needing access to the enclosing class's properties, which would be inaccessible if the inner class wasn't static. I didn't look carefully enough at the code example :-o

Comment: I had researched this and found an answer (which does not seem to work for me) indicating this needing to be static.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289964/jackson-json-type-mapping-inner-class  So I'm trying to get around why this won't work.