# HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'walletName' is not present

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I work with `Java/ Spring MVC RESTful` app and get `400 HTTP status error` while doing a `POST` request. The `@RestController` method is provided,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper> generateAddress(@RequestParam("walletName") String walletName,
                                                             @RequestParam("currencyName") String currencyName) {

        logger.info("walletName {} and currencyName {}", walletName, currencyName);

        // return if the wallet name or the currency is null
        if (Objects.isNull(walletName) || Objects.isNull(currencyName)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.generateAddress(walletName, currencyName);

        if (Objects.isNull(walletInfo)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        WalletInfoWrapper walletInfoWrapper = new WalletInfoWrapper();
        walletInfoWrapper.setName(walletInfo.getName());

        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(walletInfoWrapper, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

The `POST` request in the `Postman` provided below,

[image]

The error message informs, `Required String parameter 'walletName' is not present`

[image]

I can also provide the code for the `services` and the `dataase` layers for observing the drop-down operations. What is the issue here?

`UPDATE`

I updated the `Postman` request like this and still having the same error,

[image]

`UPDATE 1`

I still have the same issue,

I `POST` with the data,

```
{"walletName":"puut","currencyName":"Bitcoin"}
```

The code is provided below,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper> generateAddress(@RequestBody WalletWithMoneyRequest walletWithMoneyRequest) {

        String walletName = walletWithMoneyRequest.getWalletName();

        String currencyName = walletWithMoneyRequest.getCurrencyName();

        logger.info("walletName {} and currencyName {}", walletName, currencyName);

        // return if the wallet name or the currency is null
        if (Objects.isNull(walletName) || Objects.isNull(currencyName)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.generateAddress(walletName, currencyName);

        if (Objects.isNull(walletInfo)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        WalletInfoWrapper walletInfoWrapper = new WalletInfoWrapper();
        walletInfoWrapper.setName(walletInfo.getName());

        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(walletInfoWrapper, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

The `POJO` is provided,

```
private class WalletWithMoneyRequest {

        String walletName;

        String currencyName;

        public WalletWithMoneyRequest(String walletName, String currencyName) {
            this.walletName = walletName;
            this.currencyName = currencyName;
        }

        public WalletWithMoneyRequest() {
        }

        public String getWalletName() {
            return walletName;
        }

        public String getCurrencyName() {
            return currencyName;
        }

        public void setCurrencyName(String currencyName) {
            this.currencyName = currencyName;
        }

        public void setWalletName(String walletName) {
            this.walletName = walletName;
        }
    }
```

This is the error message,

[image]

Here ia the Tomcat server info,

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver: 08/19/2017 19:45:55 - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `mobi.puut.controllers.WalletRestController$WalletWithMoneyRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `mobi.puut.controllers.WalletRestController$WalletWithMoneyRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

`Tomcat Localhost log`

[image]

`Tomcat Catalina log`
[image]

Comment: It seems like you are sending a JSON string as a parameter, but that's not what your controller expects. Or is that just how it looks in Postman?

Comment: How to make the controller understand it?

Comment: Note: RESTful requests usually accept GET or POST parameters and return JSON.

Comment: @Powerlord, the ```@ResponseBody``` is implicit on  methods of ```@RestController``` annotated classes. I was unaware of the ```@RequestBody``` implicit annotation.

Comment: @Artin, do you have any output from your server's console or log that might indicate why your server doesn't like your request?

Comment: Yes, I do have one message, have a look in the updated post

Comment: Saw the output. Good. Try making your class WalletWithMoneyRequest public instead of private.

Comment: Making it `public` doesn't help and still I get `HTTP status of 400`. Though I think we have cornered the issue with the error message provided in the question.

Comment: Make WalletWithMoneyRequest its own outer class. Jackson seems to be harder to use when marshaling json to an inner class. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289964/jackson-json-type-mapping-inner-class . This is also worth a read: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html  copied from linked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is expecting 2 request parameters that normally look like this: /someurl?walletName=my-wallets-name&currencyName=dollars.

You're sending a json string in the post body, but no formal parameters. You need to update either your POST, or your controller to make the two ends agree. I think you probably want to replace the two @RequestParam annotated Strings, with a Java pojo that has two String members: walletName and currencyName, drop that pojo in your request method as an argument and precede it with the annotation @RequestBody. This will match your json post.

To have your controller accept the post with JSON in the body edit it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper> generateAddress(@RequestBody
    WalletWithMoneyRequest myJsonRequestComingIn) {
    logger.info("walletName {} and currencyName {}", myJsonRequestComingIn.getWalletName(), myJsonRequestComingIn.getCurrencyName());
```

And your pojo

```
public class WalletWithMoneyRequest{ 

    private String walletName;
    private String currencyName;

    //getters and setters down here.
```

Comment: I avoided providing an explicit answer, so that if you're trying to learn something new, you have the opportunity to figure things out. Let me know and I'll update with a code example, if you need it.

Comment: The code sample will be helpful with the answer. if you do so, please, provide both of the ways `(update either the POST, or the controller)` to execute the operation correctly.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I have posted. I accepted your though

Comment: @Artin, great. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

In your Postman request, instead of sending JSON, send the values as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

[image]

Comment: Same error as before, I have updated the answer with the info

Comment: @Artin sorry, try the `x-www-form-urlencoded` it will send the parameters in the URL like @zerpsed mentioned

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on zerpsed's answer.

Change the signature to:

```
public ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper> generateAddress(@ResponseBody WalletPOJO walletCurrency)
```

Where the WalletPOJO has the two fields walletName and currencyName

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is solved for now. I have used a `POJO` as suggested with the `@RequestBody` parameter in the `RESTful` method. The catch here is I need to make the `POJO` out of the class (in the same file though) and later, put in the entity directory as an entity.

```
class WalletWithMoneyRequest {

    String walletName;

    String currencyName;

    public WalletWithMoneyRequest(String walletName, String currencyName) {
        this.walletName = walletName;
        this.currencyName = currencyName;
    }

    public WalletWithMoneyRequest() {
    }

    public String getWalletName() {
        return walletName;
    }

    public String getCurrencyName() {
        return currencyName;
    }

    public void setCurrencyName(String currencyName) {
        this.currencyName = currencyName;
    }

    public void setWalletName(String walletName) {
        this.walletName = walletName;
    }
}
```

The main issue is believe was an error in the `HQL`,

[image]

I wrote `currency =: currency` where it should be `currency = :currency`

I still can't have the data in the database as I will need to modify the method in the `database` layer.

Answer (score 0):

En POSTMAN set variables in params
[image]